# Read only Unread email using pop3 c#

Tags: c#

I want to read only unread emails using pop3.I have done this with imap but now i also want this with pop3. I dont want that each time download email and save it to local database and compare it for next time. I want directly unread email from server using pop3.

Answer (score 1):

POP3 does not provide read/unread information, it does not have a command to get only unread e-mail.

It's an old protocol from the days you didn't leave messages on the server because:

1. you didn't have always-on connections
2. server disk space was expensive
3. there was no web-mail
4. most people didn't have multiple computers

So there really wasn't a point in leaving messages and managing them on the server (and for big enterprises that did need it there's IMAP)

So, sorry, it's IMAP or a local DB to detect read e-mails, there's really no other way.

According to Wikipedia POP4 adds this capability but POP4 is in the "informal suggestion" phase for more then a decade now with no one supporting it - so I wouldn't hold my breath waiting for servers to support it.

Comment: +1, I just want to add that technically if you do not execute the DELE command [(see RFC1939)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1939.txt), messages *can* remain on the server.  However, as noted in chapter 8 of the same RFC, that is not really the recommended way of using POP3.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example of reading email messages from POP3.

http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Fetch-and-read-email-messages-with-attachments-from-GMAIL-POP3-mail-server-in-ASPNet.aspx

You can download unread emails via pop3 like following link.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdav_101/archive/2007/11/29/ews-csharp-list-unread-inbox-messages-using-a-restriction.aspx

Comment: Your first link does not read only unread e-mail, the second link uses exchange and not POP3